# Profile view number is off

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I took a look at somebody's profile four times, but it is showing that nobody has visited their profile. Why?

Comment: It takes some time to update that information. Check again tomorrow.

Comment: Alright, but it was already yesterday that I visited his profile. Does it take thát long?

Comment: It shouldn't take that long. Which user are you talking about?